# WPF Metro Window full screen

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, fullscreen, mahapps.metro

I'm currently working on a WPF application and I don't find how to make my application in full screen.
I am using MahApps.Metro so my mainwindow's type is Controls.MetroWindow.

I tried this :

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="MyProject.MainWindow"
                      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                      xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
                      xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:MyProject.Views"
                      WindowStyle="None"
                      ResizeMode="NoResize"
                      WindowState="Maximized"
                      Title="MyProject">
```

But it doesn't hide the Windows taskbar. But it works when I use a simple Window. I looked at the MetroWindow source code, it inherits the Window class, so I don't understand why it's not working.

The only way I found to have a full screen window with Metro, is to set the *IgnoreTaskbarOnMaximize* propery to true and remove the *ResizeMode="NoResize"* (see code below), run the app and maximize it.

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="MyProject.MainWindow"
                      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                      xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
                      xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:MyProject.Views"
                      WindowStyle="None"
                      IgnoreTaskbarOnMaximize="True"
                      Title="MyProject">
```

But I would like to hide the Minimize and Maximize button..
Have you got any ideas to start a Controls.MetroWindow in full screen ?

Comment: This is an inherent property of the MahApps.Metro window. MahApps.Metro's default window has several P/Invokes to prevent the window from covering the taskbar when maximized.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue. You should report it as a bug [Here](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues)

Simple **workaround** for now could be:

Keep your xaml the same as you got to:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="MyProject.MainWindow"
                      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                      xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
                      xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:MyProject.Views"
                      WindowStyle="None"
                      IgnoreTaskbarOnMaximize="True"
                      Title="MyProject">
```

and in the `Window`'s code-behind:

```cs
public MainWindow() {
  InitializeComponent();
  Loaded += OnLoaded;
}

private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs) {
  WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
  ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
  ShowMaxRestoreButton = false;
  ShowMinButton = false;
  Loaded -= OnLoaded;
}
```

This will give you the behavior you want. We pretty much set the state(maximized), hide min/max buttons  with the `Loaded` event and only do it once.

Comment: It's exactly what I need ! Thanks a lot ! Ok, I will report it.

Comment: @JuniorD. I've reported it today : https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues/797

Answer (score 5):

with the latest [alpha](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MahApps.Metro/0.11.2.20-ALPHA) version you have two different ways to get this:

first

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="MyProject.MainWindow"
                      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                      xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
                      xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:MyProject.Views"
                      ResizeMode="NoResize"
                      WindowState="Maximized"
                      IgnoreTaskbarOnMaximize="True"
                      Title="MyProject">
```

second

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="MyProject.MainWindow"
                      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                      xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
                      xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:MyProject.Views"
                      UseNoneWindowStyle="True"
                      WindowState="Maximized"
                      Title="MyProject">
```

with the second solution you have also no titlebar, no min, max, close buttons